# Diferença entre escape, encodeURI e encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre estas três funções, e quando utilizar cada uma delas?

1. `escape()`
2. `encodeURI()`
3. `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Tem uma resposta para essa pergunta na versão em inglês
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/when-are-you-supposed-to-use-escape-instead-of-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Conforme o MDN:

### Função [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

> **Nota:** conforme [**Microsoft Docs**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/escape-function-javascript) e [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Escape_sequences) a função `escape` é obsoleta, `encodeURI` e `encodeURIComponent` em seu lugar (dependendo da necessidade)

A forma hexadecimal para caracteres, cujo valor de unidade de código é `0xFF` ou menos, é uma sequencia de escape de dois dígitos: `%xx`. Para os caracteres com uma unidade de código maior, o formato de quatro dígitos `%uxxxx` é usado.

Ela não irá escapar os seguintes caracteres:

```
@ * _ + - . /
```

---

### Função [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

A função `encodeURIComponent` codifica um componente *"Uniform Resource Identifier"* (URI), substituindo cada instância de certos caracteres por uma, duas, três ou quatro sequencias de escape que representam a codificação UTF-8 do caractere (somente serão quatro sequencias de escape para caracteres compostos por dois caracteres "de substituição").

Ele não irá escapar os seguintes caracteres:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

---

### Função [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Não codifica caracteres que têm um significado especial (caracteres reservados) para um URI. O exemplo a seguir mostra todas as partes que um *"URI Scheme"* pode conter. Observe como determinados caracteres são usados para significar significado especial:

```
http://username:password@www.example.com:80/path/to/file.php?foo=316&bar=this+has+spaces#anchor
```

Por isso `encodeURI` não codifica caracteres que são necessários para formular um URI completo. Além disso, ele  não codifica alguns caracteres adicionais, conhecidos como "marcas não reservadas", que não têm um propósito reservado, mas são permitidos em um URI "como está" (veja o [**RFC2396**](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt))

Ela não irá escapar os seguintes caracteres:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #
```

Comment: Quando acabar o período, dou recompensa nessa.